# The argument 'filename' must be a file URL object, file URL string, or absolute path string. Received 'http://localhost/eslintrc.cjs'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm receiving the below error when running unit-tests in a `Vue 3 JS`. I assume there is an incompatibility in the underlying packages, but I don't know how to find it and fix it.

```
$ vue-cli-service test:unit
  [                         ] 0% () WEBPACK  Compiling...

  [======================== ] 95% (emitting)

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors

The argument 'filename' must be a file URL object, file URL string, or absolute path string. Received 'http://localhost/eslintrc.cjs'

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  The argument 'filename' must be a file URL object, file URL string, or absolute path string. Received 'http://localhost/eslintrc.cjs'
  
  - child-compiler.js:169 
    [web-frontend]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18
  
  - Compiler.js:564 
    [web-frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:564:11
  
  - Compiler.js:1183 
    [web-frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1183:17
  
  
  - task_queues:96 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5
  

  [=========================] 99% (done) WEBPACK  Failed to compile with 2 error(s)
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "web-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/server-renderer": "^3.0.4",
    "Buffer": "^0.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
    "openapi-client-axios": "^4.4.9",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-meta": "^3.0.0-alpha.9",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^2.0.0",
    "workbox-background-sync": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-broadcast-update": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-build": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-cli": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-core": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-expiration": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-google-analytics": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-navigation-preload": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-precaching": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-range-requests": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-routing": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-strategies": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-streams": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-sw": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.2",
    "workbox-window": "^6.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.22",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-beta.14",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^10.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cypress": "*",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vuejs-accessibility": "^1.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.60.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, reverting `eslint` to `"eslint": "^7.17.0",` fixes the problem. I would love a better explanation, however, as I don't understand why this happens, what library actually causes it (so I'm not sure where to file an issue), or how to not be stuck on `eslint`.

Comment: same here with vue2 and webpack 5 ! I had to revert to "eslint": "7.17.0" from 8.13.0